# How to add two two tables of contents to my document?

Tags: table-of-contents, etoc

I need two tables of contents: one has to be short, it is an overview; the other has to be detailed and must contain every section. This latter will be inserted in the end of my document, just after my references section. I did not find here any topic which could help me to find exactly how to do it. I believe that my preamble is quiet complicated. It could explain the reason why my toc settings has no effects on the output. This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,12pt,twoside,openright,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titling}
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize\itshape}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalsize\itshape}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalsize\itshape}

%%%%%%%points pour chapitres dans toc%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{3pt}%espace entre chapitres
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for chapters
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[numberedbib,nosectionbib]{apacite}
\usepackage[makeindex]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=npr, title=Index des noms] 
\makeindex[name=mat, title=Index des matières]

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
% We don't want chapter and section numbers
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[CE]{\textit{A name}} % even pages: chapter title
\fancyhead[CO]{\textit\leftmark} % odd pages: book title


%%%%%%%%%%%%Pas de N° de chapitres%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
    {\centering\Large\bfseries}% format of chapter
    {\large\normalfont\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\enskip\thechapter}% format of the label
    {.5\baselineskip}{} % space between the two
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{25pt}{35pt} % spaces around \chapter{}, {left}{before}{after}
 
%\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  %{\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%épigraphe%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{}% Not necessary...
\newenvironment{chapquote}[2][2em]
  {\setlength{\@tempdima}{#1}%
   \def\chapquote@author{#2}%
   \parshape 1 \@tempdima \dimexpr\textwidth-2\@tempdima\relax%
   \itshape}
  {\par\normalfont\hfill---\ 
 \chapquote@author\hspace{\@tempdima}\par\bigskip\par\bigskip}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%Numérotation en chiffres arabes%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\frontmatter{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \@mainmatterfalse
  %\pagenumbering{roman}% Don't reset
}
\renewcommand\mainmatter{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \@mainmattertrue
  %\pagenumbering{arabic}% Don't reset
}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\begin{document}
\title{A title}
\author{A name}
\date{}
\maketitle


\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Sommaire}
\tableofcontents
\frontmatter

\mainmatter
\part{A part}

\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum
\section{A section}
\lipsum
\subsection{A subsection}

\subsubsection{A subsubsection}



\part{Another part}

\chapter{Another chapter}

\section{Another section}

\subsection{Another subsection}

\subsubsection{Another subsubsection}


\backmatter
\chapter{Conclusion}



\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table des matières détaillée}
\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Two things I see: first, none of these two tocs appear as a section in the toc itself. Why?; second, could you please add your suggestion to \headheight issue?

Comment: I've just modified \headheight issue : \setlength{\headheight}{14.49998pt}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-2.49998pt}... but it does not fix my toc demand.

Comment: I just edited my answer to incorporate your additional requests.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `\tableofcontents` internally uses `\@starttoc`—a macro which inputs the .toc-file and immediately afterwards destroys it via `\newwrite...\immediate\openout` so that it can be written anew at the end of the LaTeX-run from the .aux-file that came into being during the LaTeX-run. Thus you cannot have several calls to `\tableofcontents` as already the first call destroys the .toc-file.

What you can do is patching a copy of the `\@starttoc`-command so that it does not destroy the .toc-file and ensure that with all instances of `\tableofcontents` but the last instance that patched copy is used instead of the original `\@starttoc`-command. The look of the patch depends on how recent your LaTeX-kernel is. Then with each call to `\tableofcontents` you can adjust `tocdepth`.

You can get "Sommaire" into "Table des matières détaillée" and vice versa, e.g., by loading the package [tocbibind](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocbibind)  and via

```
\begingroup\addtocontents{toc}{\string\if...}\..true\tableofcontents\addtocontents{toc}{\string\fi}\endgroup
```

placing some `\if... \fi` around the corresponding entries of the .toc-file.

In the example below [tocbibind](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocbibind) is loaded in a way where "Sommaire" and "Table des matières détaillée" are listed on the part-level.

```latex
\documentclass[hidelinks,12pt,twoside,openright,a4paper]{book}
\setlength{\headheight}{14.49998pt}%
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-2.49998pt}%
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\@ifdefinable\my@starttoc{\let\my@starttoc\@starttoc}%
\patchcmd{\my@starttoc}{%
  \if@filesw\expandafter\newwrite\csname tf@#1\endcsname
  \immediate\openout\csname tf@#1\endcsname\jobname.#1\relax
  \fi
}{}{}{%
  \@latex@error{\string\my@starttoc\space could not be patched to be 
                \MessageBreak a variant of \string\@starttoc\space that does not
                \MessageBreak destroy the file%
   }{%
     Via \string\show\space look at the definition of \string\@starttoc\space and
     \MessageBreak modify the patching-directive accordingly.%
   }%
}%
\makeatother

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage[other]{tocbibind}% Add table of contents etc to contents on part-level
\tocotherhead{part}
\newif\ifsommaireintoc\sommaireintocfalse
\newif\ifmatieresdetaileeintoc\matieresdetaileeintoctrue



\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titling}
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize\itshape}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalsize\itshape}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalsize\itshape}

%%%%%%%points pour chapitres dans toc%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{3pt}%espace entre chapitres
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for chapters
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[numberedbib,nosectionbib]{apacite}
\usepackage[makeindex]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=npr, title=Index des noms] 
\makeindex[name=mat, title=Index des matières]

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
% We don't want chapter and section numbers
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[CE]{\textit{A name}} % even pages: chapter title
\fancyhead[CO]{\textit\leftmark} % odd pages: book title


%%%%%%%%%%%%Pas de N° de chapitres%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
    {\centering\Large\bfseries}% format of chapter
    {\large\normalfont\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\enskip\thechapter}% format of the label
    {.5\baselineskip}{} % space between the two
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{25pt}{35pt} % spaces around \chapter{}, {left}{before}{after}
 
%\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  %{\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%épigraphe%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{}% Not necessary...
\newenvironment{chapquote}[2][2em]
  {\setlength{\@tempdima}{#1}%
   \def\chapquote@author{#2}%
   \parshape 1 \@tempdima \dimexpr\textwidth-2\@tempdima\relax%
   \itshape}
  {\par\normalfont\hfill---\ 
 \chapquote@author\hspace{\@tempdima}\par\bigskip\par\bigskip}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%Numérotation en chiffres arabes%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\frontmatter{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \@mainmatterfalse
  %\pagenumbering{roman}% Don't reset
}
\renewcommand\mainmatter{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \@mainmattertrue
  %\pagenumbering{arabic}% Don't reset
}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\begin{document}
\title{A title}
\author{A name}
\date{}
\maketitle

% Only part, chapter and section:
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Sommaire}
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\let\@starttoc=\my@starttoc
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\ifsommaireintoc}%
\sommaireintocfalse
\matieresdetaileeintoctrue
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\fi}%
\endgroup
\frontmatter

\mainmatter
\part{A part}

\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum
\section{A section}
\lipsum
\subsection{A subsection}

\subsubsection{A subsubsection}



\part{Another part}

\chapter{Another chapter}

\section{Another section}

\subsection{Another subsection}

\subsubsection{Another subsubsection}


\backmatter
\chapter{Conclusion}

\cleardoublepage
% part, chapter, section, subsection and subsubsection:
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table des matières détaillée}
\begingroup
\matieresdetaileeintocfalse
\sommaireintoctrue
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\ifmatieresdetaileeintoc}%
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\fi}%
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you used the `memoir` class (a superset of `book` and `report`) then you can have as many TOCs (or LOFs or LOTs) as you want. The User Manual (`> texdoc memoir`) shows both a short TOC and a regular TOC.